# WPF usercontrol showdialog problem

Tags: wpf, exception, user-controls, showdialog

There is a MainWindow, a usercontrol which is located in my MainWindow and a OtherForm which I am going to show from usercontrol. I sent OtherForm as parameter from MainWindow to usercontrol. And in usercontrol I am calling `OtherForm.showdialog`. When I show it the second time, I am getting "Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed" problem.

**Code**

In MainWindow class

```
void Example()
{
   usercontrol.Load(new Otherform{ variable= 1 });
}
```

In Usercontrol class

```
private Window _form;
public void Load(window form)
{
    _form=form;
}

void ExampleInUSerControl
{
   _form.VerifyAccess();
   _form.Activate();
   _form.ShowActivated = true;
   _form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message in this case is pretty accurate:  once a Window is closed, it's closed for good.  Since `ShowDialog()` always closes the window, you need to create a new instance of the window every time you call `ShowDialog()`.

One fairly simple way to accomplish this in your example is to have the `Load` event take an argument of type `Func<Window>`:

In the MainWindow:

```
private Window MakeWindow()
{
   return new MyWindow();
}

private void Example()
{
   usercontrol.Load(MakeWindow);
}
```

In the user control:

```
public void Load(Func<T> makeWindow)
{
   _form = makeWindow();
   ...
}
```

Note, by the way, that there should be no reason to call `Activate` or set `ShowActivated` - `ShowDialog` will do all that.  And I don't know why you'd call `VerifyAccess` either.